# When and Deferred

Tags: javascript, jquery, each, .when

I'm looping through an array, when all fileRead deferred are resolved, 'done' is logged.

```
$.when.apply(null, $.each(files, function(index, file){

        return self.fileRead.read(file).done(function(fileB64){
            self.fileShow(file, fileB64, fileTemplate);
        });

    })).done(function() {  
        console.log('done');

    })
```

The problem is, I only wish done to be logged once the fileShow method has returned.

1. Does this fileShow method also need to implement deferred. Or can it just return?
2. How can I modify the loop so console.log('done') is ran once all fileShow methods have been executed?

Comment: Use `$.map` instead of `$.each` so you can return the `Deferred` objects. `$.each` returns its first argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$.map` instead of `$.each`. This returns an array of the `Deferred` objects returned by your iteration function, and these can then be passed to `$.when`.

```
$.when.apply(null, $.map(function(index, file) {
    return self.fileRead.read(file).done(function(fileB64) {
        self.fileShow(file, fileB64, fileTemplate);
    });

})).done(function() {  
    console.log('done');

});
```

Comment: This does not work, it just logs 'done' straight away